# Need sqlite query to delete a row from a table with minimum value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to delete a row with minimum value of a particular field from a table if number of records less than 5;

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with sub-selects for the aggregate `min` and `count` functions:

```
DELETE FROM the_table WHERE
  the_field = (SELECT min(the_field) FROM the_table)
  AND (SELECT count(*) FROM the_table) < 5;
```